# How can I manipulate the data from Firebase Authentication? Are there any way to work with those data (identifier, providers, created, etc.)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I'd like to extract all users who haven't been signed in to the App for the last 180 days.
From what I know it's only possible to see a max number of 250 users at a time and also you can sort the data using the fields Identifier, Created, Signed In and User UID.
Could anyone help me with some information where can I find either the database where that information is or any other way to get insights about it?

I appreciate any help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the console, the only other supported way to work with user accounts in Firebase Authentication is the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin). You will write code to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`auth:export`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#auth-commands) command from the Firebase CLI.
It will exports all the active project's user accounts to a JSON or CSV file.

You'll find the CSV or JSON formats [here in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#file_format) and, as you can see, you get the fields you're looking for: Identifier, Created (in EPOCH time), last Signed In (in EPOCH time) and User UID. You can easily import the CSV to Excel or to Google Sheets in order to sort and filter.